# Default values for record properties

Tags: java, record

If I have a Java record with 2 properties and I want to define default values for the properties which should be used instead of null. I can either override the getters:

```
public record MyRecord(Set<String> strings, Boolean required) {

    @Override
    public Boolean required() {
        return Objects.requireNonNullElse(this.required, Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> strings() {
        return Objects.requireNonNullElse(this.strings, Set.of());
    }
}
```

…or I can achieve much the same thing by overriding the default constructor:

```
public record MyRecord(Set<String> strings, Boolean required) {

    public MyRecord(Set<String> strings, Boolean required) {
        this.strings = Objects.requireNonNullElse(strings, Set.of());
        this.required = Objects.requireNonNullElse(required, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

Both of these seem a bit verbose, is there a more concise way to assign default values to record properties?

Comment: The second option seems to be the most correct

Comment: A Lombok builder would do this well too... depends if you value having a record specifically. Java should add optional parameters with default value as well as call by name (or whatever is the name for the syntax allowing to do `method(param1 = "bla"`), this would eliminate even more use cases for Lombok, like in Kotlin or Scala

Comment: You can also add constructors, as long as they eventually (possibly through multiple calls to `this(...)` calls the generated constructor. For instance; `public MyRecord() { this(Set.of(), true); }`

Comment: if you are using Spring and these are managed beans, `@DefaultValue` is another option.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Overriding the accessor methods like in your first variant violates the expectation that you can create an equal object using the accessor methods and the canonical constructor. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html#:%7E:text=For%20all%20record,equals(copy).)

> For all record classes, the following invariant must hold: if a record R's components are `c1, c2, ... cn`, then if a record instance is copied as follows:
>
> ```
>     R copy = new R(r.c1(), r.c2(), ..., r.cn());
> ```
>
> then it must be the case that `r.equals(copy)`.

But with your overridden accessor method, the following assertion fails:

```java
MyRecord r1 = new MyRecord(null, null), r2 = new MyRecord(r1.strings(), r1.required());
assert r1.equals(r2);
```

because the internal fields contain different data.

So the only correct way to fix input data is during the construction, e.g.

```java
public record MyRecord(Set<String> strings, Boolean required) {
    public MyRecord {
        if(strings == null) strings = Set.of();
        if(required == null) required = true;
    }
}
```

However, you shouldn’t do this `null` handling at all. Collections should never be `null` and using `Boolean` for the constructor implies having a `Boolean` record component type in general, i.e. also returned by the accessor method. And writing `new MyRecord(null, null)` instead of `new MyRecord(Set.of(), true)` doesn’t even save much typing.

If you want to support default values, you should overload the constructor, e.g.

```java
public record MyRecord(Set<String> strings, boolean required) {
    public MyRecord {
        strings = Set.copyOf(strings); // enforce non-null immutable set
    }
    public MyRecord() {
        this(Set.of(), true);
    }
}
```

So you can use `new MyRecord()` for the defaults. Or you consider that records are immutable, so constructing multiple instances of defaults isn’t necessary

```java
public record MyRecord(Set<String> strings, boolean required) {
    public static final MyRecord DEFAULT = new MyRecord(Set.of(), true);
    public MyRecord {
        strings = Set.copyOf(strings); // enforce non-null immutable set
    }
}
```

and use `MyRecord.DEFAULT` whenever you need the default values. Of course, you still can provide overloaded constructors for the cases that only one parameter should have default values, if that is needed.

Comment: this is _exactly_ what Spring does internally. Since they control the creation of the instances (beans), they also allow `@DefaultValue`s annotations on record attributes.